# c++ code throws unexpected characters in output

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have pasted a part of code snippet from my program, the output of the code gives some unrequired characters, please look into it and let me know the obvious logical reasons behind it.

```
class print {
FILE *pFile;
vector <char> st;
public:
char *formatForHtml(string str, string htmlTag) {
    string strBegin;
    strBegin = "<";
    strBegin.append(htmlTag);
    strBegin.append(">");
    strBegin.append(str);
    string strEnd = "</";
    strEnd.append(htmlTag);
    strEnd.append(">");
    strBegin.append(strEnd);
    st.resize(strBegin.size());
    for (int i =0;i <strBegin.size();i++) {
        st[i] = strBegin[i];
    }
    return &st[0];
}
void generatePath() { 
    char fileName[_MAX_FNAME];
    _makepath(fileName,"C:","\\Users\\vinitg\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\continous_beam_cpp.cpp\\", "myf9", "html");
    pFile = fopen(fileName,"a+");
}
void writeInFile() {
    string str = "DESIGN OF A CONTINOUS BEAM!";
    char *procString;
    procString = formatForHtml(str, "p");
    fprintf(pFile, procString);
    fclose(pFile);
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "file:///C:/Users/vinitg/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202010/Projects/continous_beam_cpp.cpp/myF9.html",NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
}
void passString (char g[]) {
    cout << &g[0];
}
};
int main() {
    print generateReport;
    generateReport.generatePath();
    generateReport.writeInFile();
    cout << "Press any one key to continue..";
    getch();
}`
```

you must have already guessed that a HTML file created and results are displayed in html format, pasted below is the output(with unwanted characters)

`DESIGN OF A CONTINUOUS BEAM!`

`ýýýý««««««««îþ`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define a character vector and expect it to behave as a character string. The elements of the vector will not be allocated continuously. So, the statement

```
return &st[0];
```

will not return a character array/string as you expect.

**Edit**  : From the comments below, I checked the specification. After cross-checking the vector standard, the continuous memory allocation is guaranteed for the vectors, so, it was my mistake. Nevertheless, you don't need to implement a vector for getting the character pointer out.

Implement your class as given below. i.e, return the formatted string as it is from the formatForHTML function. To the file just print the contents with c_str() function of the string. No need to use the character pointers.

```
class print {
FILE *pFile;
vector <char> st;
public:
string formatForHtml(string str, string htmlTag) {
    string strBegin;
    strBegin = "<";
    strBegin.append(htmlTag);
    strBegin.append(">");
    strBegin.append(str);
    string strEnd = "</";
    strEnd.append(htmlTag);
    strEnd.append(">");
    strBegin.append(strEnd);

    return strBegin;
}
void generatePath() { 
    char fileName[_MAX_FNAME];
    _makepath(fileName,"C:","\\Users\\vinitg\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\continous_beam_cpp.cpp\\", "myf9", "html");
    pFile = fopen(fileName,"a+");
}
void writeInFile() {
    string str = "DESIGN OF A CONTINOUS BEAM!";
    string procString;
    procString = formatForHtml(str, "p");
    fprintf(pFile, procString.c_str());
    fclose(pFile);
    ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"file:///C:/Users/vinitg/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202010/Projects/continous_beam_cpp.cpp/myF9.html",NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
}
void passString (char g[]) {
    cout << &g[0];
}
};
```

Comment: You define a character vector and expect it to behave as a character string. The elements of the vector will not be allocated continuously.

In standart vector MUST be allocated continuosly, so &st[0] is right operation, that returns pointer to beginning of vector.

Comment: Not true. elements are allocated continously (that wasn't guarenteed in early versions of the C++ standard, but later got fixed).

Comment: welcome!! now you would have clearly got an idea what is written in standard books, right? It will be of terrific use in your future ;)

Answer (score 0):

All is expected. Your string have no null terminator.

Comment: @vin append null terminator at the end=) or not use fprintf and print bytes in file manual.

Answer (score 0):

`formatForHtml` returns a `char*` that isn't null delimited. You have to append `0` to it:

```
st.resize(strBegin.size() + 1);
...
st.push_back('\0');
```

Instead of returning `char*`, I'd rather return `std::string` and use `procString.c_str()` to get the raw data to write to the file.

Comment: You'd be better off with `st.push_back('0')`. Or, if you really want to do it your way, the index in the second line should be `strBegin.size()-1`.